# How to implement this using Windows forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two problems with my windows form in Visual Basic .NET 2008. If you have worked with *sticky notes* you will understand me better.

[image]

Now my problems:

1. If you look you'll see the background color of number 1 and 2 are
   diffrent but both belongs to the same control. How is this possible?
2. In right bottom corner, there is something by which a user can resize the form.
   How I can do this?

Comment: Updated answer based on your need for drawing on a textbox.

Answer (score 4):

Item 1:  I think you are referring to LinearGradient Brush-- look in the System.Drawing.Drawing2D class.

Item 2: They are drawing a resize handler.  You can try using the ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip method or draw your own.

**Update:**

Per your comments, you can look into [Owner-drawing a Windows.Forms TextBox](http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/)

Comment: With this tutorial you can add gradient background to your form http://www.getdotnetcode.com/nexDotNet/030005H2GradientBg4WinFormVB/H2GradientBg4WinFormVB.htm

Comment: @Maysam Thanks for code but I need to do that with my text edit control not form!

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a gradient background by overriding `OnPaintBackground()`:

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // set these to whatever you want 
        Color color1 = Color.LightBlue; 
        Color color2 = Color.DarkBlue;

        using (Brush backbrush =
            new LinearGradientBrush(e.ClipRectangle, color1, color2,
                LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backbrush, e.ClipRectangle);
        }

    }
```

You can show the size gripper by setting the form's SizeGripStyle to Show:

```
SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Show;
```

Or just set it in the designer.

EDIT: Look at [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/alphablendtextbox.aspx?fid=15959&fr=11#xx0xx) for creating a transparent textbox (if the textbox is transparent, the gradient form background will show through.)

Comment: Thanks But I need to do LinearGradientBrush with Text Edit control not form! 2 - SizeGripStyle  doesn't work when I set FormBorderStyle to None!

Comment: Well why didn't you say so? Please be clearer. You'll have to write or obtain a textbox which supports custom painting. Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/alphablendtextbox.aspx?fid=15959&fr=11#xx0xx